# Google API (Таблицы)

Tags: c#, google-spreadsheet

Пытаюсь к приложению прикрепить прайс, который находится на Гугл диске. Начал пробовать подключать API. Но на тестовом приложении выпадает ошибка

> Google.GoogleApiException: "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Requested entity was not found. [404]

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GoogleSheetsAPI4_v1console
{
 class Program
 {
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets }; // static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "WindowsDoors";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_id.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);


            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });



        String spreadsheetId2 = "price";
        String range2 = "1!F5";  // update cell F5 
        ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
        valueRange.MajorDimension = "COLUMNS";//"ROWS";//COLUMNS

        var oblist = new List<object>() { "My Cell Text" };
        valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };

        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest update = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetId2, range2);
        update.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW;
        UpdateValuesResponse result2 = update.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("done!");

    }
```

Код для тест нашел здесь же, на иностранной части.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел косяк. Вместо названия книги: 
    String spreadsheetId2 = "price";
Должен стоять ее ИД.